# Single integer Value Patch - Quartz composer

Tags: quartz-composer

I am looking for a patch that allows me to input a number on the inspector and then outputs it.

This way I can share this values across other inputs.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Patch Library and create an `Input Splitter`.  It will appear on the canvas as `Virtual Splitter`.  Click on the patch you just created and press <kbd>⌘ 2</kbd> to open the Inspector Settings window, and change Type to either Index (if you want an unsigned integer) or Number (if you want a floating-point number).